# NgXS. DIfference between store.dispatch() and context.dispatch()?

Tags: angular, ngxs

In NgXS i have two ways to trigger an event from a state to another state:

1. Call dispatch() from global Store
2. Call dispatch() from StateContext object inside State

What's the difference between the two ways? Which method is better and why?
E.g.

```
//== state action

@Action()
doAny(context: StateContext<MyContextModel>, payload: any): void {
  context.dispatch(new AnotherStateAction());
  // this._store.dispatch(new AnotherStateAction()); this code will do the same
}
```

Docs: https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/state#dispatching-actions-from-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, these methods use the same internal method of an `InternalStateOperations` service:

- [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/df9108d1b8c4024b8d319b298bfc934f340f0ab8/packages/store/src/internal/state-context-factory.ts#L16) and [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/aa2aacfd20f051413bcd0479ac16eeb80a277f3a/packages/store/src/store.ts#L35) for `StateContextFactory` that creates `StateContext` instances.
- [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/aa2aacfd20f051413bcd0479ac16eeb80a277f3a/packages/store/src/store.ts#L20) and [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/aa2aacfd20f051413bcd0479ac16eeb80a277f3a/packages/store/src/store.ts#L35) for `Store` itself.

That said, `_store` member is apparently treated as private (i.e. API is non-reliable for external use even for state class methods) so I suggest using `StateContext`instance for dispatching.